# what is the difference between Mediation id and publisher id in admob

Tags: android, admob

what is the difference between Mediation id and publisher id in admob ; m getting confused between these two which id i will use in my Android Application, and why Admob given 2 id?

```
         <com.google.ads.AdView
         xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
         android:id="@+id/ad"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
         ads:adUnitId="738a44d913034b9f"
         />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A publisher id refers to the id for a particular ad spot. Each ad spot defines a certain size and can have filters. Ad ad spot is typically limited to a single app (there is nothing stopping you from reusing across apps but you will have less clear stats per app and may lower your eCPM because they ads are no less well targeted).

A mediation id refers to a particular mediation list which will refer to one or more ad networks, one of which is probably Admob ad will be identified by it's publisher id.

If you are not yet using mediation you should be. It let's you control your ad spread at the server.

Comment: which id i will insert in my app mediation id or publisher id?

Comment: Always mediation id because it let's you delegate to a range of publisher ids.